# Scala: SBT bundle different library dependencies for each stage

Tags: java, scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a `Scala` project that I build using `SBT`. In the `build.sbt` I want to bundle some library dependencies that will ONLY be used during the `test` phase and not during the `package` phase.

For example,

If I run: `sbt test`, I might want to have a library dependency on `scala-test`, but if I run `sbt package`, I don't want the dependency on `scala-test`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: put `% "test"` at the end of the dependency

Comment: @SethTisue when I do that the jar still gets pulled when I run: "sbt package". I want it to be pulled only if I do "sbt test". I can see that in the cache/.ivy2 directory

Comment: I think you will have to put your test code in a different subproject.

Comment: But also, I wonder what the problem is with having the dependency retrieved. If the dependency isn't on the classpath in any inappropriate context, and isn't actually bundled when you run `package`, then what's the problem with having it retrieved? Curious.

Comment: @SethTisue the first comment works for me. thank you. If you could "Reply" to my question, I will be able to "Accept" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `% "test"` at the end of the dependency and you're good to go!